# seq command leaving off expected final value

Tags: unix, sequence, seq

I was messing around with the seq command and noticed that when I do: `seq 0 .005 .1`, the output omits the expected `0.1` at the end of the returned list.  The final value displayed is `0.95`.

```
$ seq 0 .005 .1
0
0.005
0.01
0.015
0.02
0.025
0.03
0.035
0.04
0.045
0.05
0.055
0.06
0.065
0.07
0.075
0.08
0.085
0.09
0.095
```

Anything else I try - such as seq 0 .005 .05 - results in the last value being the expected one written as the last argument in the command.

```
$ seq 0 .005 .05
0
0.005
0.01
0.015
0.02
0.025
0.03
0.035
0.04
0.045
0.05
```

Anyone know why this is so?

Comment: `seq` is not part of bash, and the implementations supporting floating-point numbers don't require `bash` to run. It's actually not a POSIX-standard command either, and otherwise has no specification formally governing its behavior -- so there's no formal definition of what is and isn't correct for it to do, other than any man page or documentation your particular implementation shipped with.

Comment: In consequence, I'm removing the `bash` tag from this question.

Comment: It doesn't happen in my system, but it's probably due to rounding errors (.005 and 0.1 cannot represented exactly in binary). Try this `seq 0 .005 .1001`.

Comment: @redneb, well -- cannot be represented exactly with IEEE 754 floating-point. There *are* other binary representations. :)